# g++ compiling error: /bin/ld: Invalid BFD target 'maxdata:0x80000000'

Tags: gcc

We are migrating some very simple C++ programs from AIX Server to Linux. The code is compiling fine on AIX server.

I tried to compile the C++ code in the Linux server. But the command line below failed:

> g++ map2key.cpp -o map2key -nodefaultlibs -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lc -Xlinker -bmaxdata:0x8000000

With the error message:

> /bin/ld: invalid BFD target `maxdata:0x80000000'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The C++ program should be compiled and executable file should be generated

If you can help, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Do you need that `-bmaxdata` (minimum heap size) argument?  ~13M is not a huge heap these days.

Comment: You can reduce the command to `g++ map2key.cpp -o map2key`